# How do I change the remote path for an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, svn

I have an Xcode project I haven't opened in a while that is hosted on a remote Subversion server that I get to via ssh.

The URL to the server has changed, so my project can't reach the remote server any more.

For git repositories, Xcode displays a "remotes" tab in the Source Control menu's "Configure [projectname]" menu. I don't see a way to do this for projects managed under subversion.

How do I edit the URL for my remote repo under Xcode 5.1 (or later, presumably.)

Thank in advance for your help.